# Establecer una variable al hacer onclick

Tags: php, onclick

El problema es que necesito algun metodo para al hacer onclick en un determinado enlace cambie la variable 
estructura php

```
<form action="<?php echo $vari;?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Nombre">
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
<a href="#" onclick="link('https://dominio.com/login.php')">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="link('https://otrodominio.com/login2.php')">Link 2</a>
<input type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>
```

la funcion

> link(valor)

establecera la variable lo cual cambiara form action

¿Como la hago?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con la "variable estructura php"?

Comment: como tal no puedes hacerlo en php. Una vez que se interpreta la pagina, se manda al navegador cliente. Ahi ya no puedes utilizar php a no ser que hagas llamadas ajax. Por tu codigo lo mas conveniente seria utilizar un javascript para que modifique el action del form.

Comment: Para esto lo mejor es usar Ajax, y ni siquiera tienes que cambiar el action, tomas la URL al hacer click y se la pasas a la petición Ajax junto con los datos.

Comment: ·@A.Cedano necesito mas detalles acerca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion que me sirvio fue

```
<script>
function cambiar(valor){
document.forms['forum'].value = valor
}
</script>
<form action="#" name="forum" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Nombre">
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">

    <a href="#" onclick="cambiar('login.php')">Login</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="cambiar('loginplus.php')">Login Premium</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo, sin meternos en la petición Ajax porque se requeriría una URL real para probarlo.

Lo que es preciso entender es que en la petición Ajax se manda un parámetro que es la `url`, donde pones la dirección a que irá dirigida la petición.

Observa que aquí he optado por algo más elegante y más práctico, en vez de links, muestro dos radio button para elegir si se quiere hacer login en un sitio o en otro.

Fíjate que además el botón `Entrar` permanece desactivado hasta que no se elige uno de los dos radio button. Cuando un radio es seleccionaro, hay una variable `url` que muestra el valor que tiene ese radio, la cual se usaría eventualmente en la petición Ajax.

La petición Ajax habría que crearla en esta parte:

```
btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
```

Ahí tendrás disponible en la variagle `url` la dirección del radio que haya quedado seleccionado y se la pasarás a Ajax con los datos del formulario que haya que enviar.

Espero que este enfoque te sirva de ayuda. Me parece mejor desde el punto de vista de *experiencia del usuario*.

En cuanto a Ajax, aquí hay varios ejemplos sobre la forma de escribir el código, puedes inspirarte en alguna de ella si no tienes experiencia con esta herramienta.

```js
var allLogin = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=login]');
var url = "";
var btnEnviar = document.getElementById('btnEnviar');


allLogin.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('change', function() {
    url = this.value;
    console.log("Seleccionaste: " + url);
    btnEnviar.disabled = false;
  });
});

btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Presionaste entrar, Ajax se enviará a\n: " + url);
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Nombre">
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="login" value="https://dominio.com/login.php">
    Login 1
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="login" value="https://otrodominio.com/login2.php">
    Login 2
  </label>
  <button id="btnEnviar" disabled>Entrar</button>
</form>
```